# Does left shift operator wrap the bits around?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

If my understanding of the left shift operator and little endianness is correct, then the value of `x` in the following should be `0` on little endian machines.

```
uint64_t x = ((uint64_t)1<<63);
```

`(uint64_t)1` in memory will look like `0x0100000000000000` and left shifting by 63 will change that to `0x0000000000000000` which is `0`. So `x` should be `0`.
But when I run the following on my x86-64 machine

```
int main()
{
    uint64_t x = ((uint64_t)1)<<63;
    printf("%lu\n", x);
}
```

The output I get is `9223372036854775808`.
What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: "Left" has nothing to do with the way the value appears in memory, but in the processor register. And no, bits shifted out do not wrap, they are lost.

Comment: Succinctly, No (shift doesn't wrap bits).  `1ULL << 63` puts the 1-bit into the most significant bit position.  That isn't 0.

Comment: @WeatherVane is that so? So bit-shift operators lead to the same result in both little-endian and big-endian machines?

Comment: Endianness affects the way values are stored, but the values themselves are the same. The way bits are shifted has nothing to do with endianness. Endianness and bit shifting are unrelated.

Comment: How would left shift be at all useful if it meant _multiply by a power of 2_ on some platforms and _unhelpfully scramble your bits_ on others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(uint64_t)1` has the value `0x0000000000000001`. How this value is represented on the memory shoudln't affect the calculation.

Shifting this value to left by 63 yields `0x8000000000000000`, which is `9223372036854775808` in decimal.

What you did wrong is the format specifier. You should use `PRIu64` (defined in `inttypes.h`) to print `uint64_t`. `%lu` is for `unsigned long` and passing data having wrong type invokes *undefined behavior*.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t x = ((uint64_t)1)<<63;
    printf("%" PRIu64 "\n", x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The shift operator does not depend on  little or big endianness. For unsigned integers it evaluates like (The C Standard, 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 4 The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
> bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of
> the result is E1 × 2E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value
> representable in the result type

That is as the arithmetic operation **E1 × 2^E2**.

So for example the expression

```
1u << 1
```

is equivalent to `1u * 2` (`1u * 2 ^ 1`).